# prometheus alertmanager mails to DL group

Tags: prometheus

need help in configuring alertmanager to send mails to DL group members.Alertmanager is working for single email address but failing for group emails. found no errors from alertmanager logs.

Comment: What is a DL group?

Comment: its a group mail id which contains 5 members in a group.

Comment: What's a group mail id? How do you address it? Standard email?

Comment: its not a standard email. its a Microsoft exchange distribution list.

Comment: i tested with telnet  and send test mail to (xx@domain.com (DL) ) each and every one in the group received mails . i configured same mail id in alert manager its not working here.